# clearInterval not working inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a countdown timer, which has a single button to toggle the start and the stop of the timer. Starting the timer and the switch between "break mode" and "session mode" works fine. The initial state of the countdown timer is paused. When I click on the Toggle Button it starts normally. When I click again, it doesn't do anything, it doesn't clear the interval. When I click again however, it doubles the interval.

Here is my code so far - the countdown function and the toggle function:

```
  startstop() {
    if (this.state.paused){
      this.setState({
        paused: false,
      });
      this.countdown(this.state.timerseconds, this.state.timerminutes, this.state.sessiontrue, this.state.paused);
    } else if (!this.state.paused){
      this.setState({
        paused: true,
      });
      this.countdown(this.state.timerseconds, this.state.timerminutes, this.state.sessiontrue, this.state.paused);
    }
  }

 countdown(seconds, minutes, sessionactive, pausedtrue){
  let s = seconds;
  let m = minutes;
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (pausedtrue){
      clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
      if (s === 0 && m > 0){
        this.setState({
          timerseconds: 59,
          timerminutes: this.state.timerminutes - 1
        })
        s = 59;
        m = m - 1;
      } else if (s > 0 && m >= 0) {
        this.setState({
          timerseconds: this.state.timerseconds - 1,
          timerminutes: this.state.timerminutes
        })
        s = s - 1;
      } else if (s === 0 && m === 0){
        if (sessionactive){
          clearInterval(interval);
          document.getElementById("beep").play();
          this.setState({
            timerseconds: 0,
            timerminutes: this.state.breaklength,
            sessiontrue: false,
          });
          this.countdown(this.state.timerseconds, this.state.timerminutes, this.state.sessiontrue, false);
        } else {
          clearInterval(interval);
          document.getElementById("beep").play();
          this.setState({
            timerseconds: 0, 
            timerminutes: this.state.sessionlength,
            sessiontrue: true,
          });
          this.countdown(this.state.timerseconds, this.state.timerminutes, this.state.sessiontrue, false)
        }
      }
    }
  }
, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `countdown` you create a new interval. You should store the reference to the first interval somewhere and use that reference in `clearInterval` when you click to pause the timer.

Another approach would be to use `this.state.paused` instead of `pausedtrue` in `if (pausedtrue)`, because `pausedtrue` is set when you call the method and never changes but `this.state.paused` can be changed and will be checked every tick.

Also I think it's not safe to use `this.state.paused` when you call the `countdown`. `setState` is asynchronous so you never know if the value in the state has been already changed or not.